# Citations occuring after fullstop incorrectly

Tags: citing

This sort of code:

```
...resulting effect \cite{Lertora2010}.
```

gives:

> resulting effect.¹

How do I make it produce:

> resulting effect¹.

I'm using:

```
\usepackage[superscript,biblabel]{cite}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want this? In English typesetting (cf French) footnotes are usually printed after the punctuation, and it makes sense to do the same with citation superscripts.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.